# How to keep the database table data unmodified if input variable is empty from php?

Tags: php, mysql

I ran into a problem, say I have the following:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE grades SET exam1=?, exam2=? WHERE user='$user' AND course='$course'");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $exam1, $exam2);
```

I have 2 different variables `$exam1, $exam2`, All of these are assigned with form data from html. However, when I submit the form, I only want to update certain data within the table, let's say I update `$exam1` and leave out the input field for the `$exam2`,

```
$exam1 = $_GET['exam1']; 
$exam2 = $_GET['exam2']; //I did not insert a value for exam2 input field
```

this will turn `grades`'s `exam2` field to `0`, as opposed to its original value.

So is there any way to prevent the empty variable from modifying the table data? I could've done 2 separate prepare statements each for a different exam, but I feel like there is got to be a better way because what if there are many columns and I only wish to update some?

Comment: Check if you have a value for `exam2` ahead of time. If you don't then select the current value from the database. Alternatively you could use the check to modify the query itself.

Comment: either you create the update columns dynamically (the only value that needs to be changed) or just include the same value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build your query dynamically.
Something like:

```
$sql = "
  UPDATE
    grades
  SET
    exam1 = ?
";

if ( ! empty($exam2) ) {
  $sql.= " , exam2 = ? "
}
$sql.= " WHERE user='$user' AND course='$course'";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

if ( ! empty($exam2) ) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ii", $exam1, $exam2);
} else {
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $exam1);
}
```

By the way, why are you using bind parameters for your `exam1` and `exam2` values but not your `user` and `course`?